# Docker container stuck running from Python SDK

Tags: python, docker

I am following the example in Docker SDK for Python: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html. But the container seems to be stuck after running and do not output anything:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docker
>>> client = docker.from_env()
>>> client.containers.run("ubuntu", "echo hello world")
```

Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: How did you determine that the container is stuck and how did you check the output?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:**

I don't know why the first time it did not progress even after `strace` showing a `download image complete` message. I killed the process and retried, this time it worked. I am running everything on a virtual machine. It seems there are some related issues with docker itself, don't think this could be an SDK issue. See for example [this](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2083). The second time I also had disabled the host antivirus (Win7 security essentials, but I'm not sure it did the trick).
**EDIT:**
Actually it is taking too long to complete also in my case. I guess it is because the first time the python process has to download the `ubuntu` image which is around 180MB in size.
**Original answer:**

Open another session and find the process id using the `ps` command. Then do `strace -p <pid>`. You'll see the that actually the process is doing something:

```
recvfrom(4, "bd\r\n{\"status\":\"Downloading\",\"pro"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 195
recvfrom(4, "bd\r\n{\"status\":\"Downloading\",\"pro"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 195
recvfrom(4, "bd\r\n{\"status\":\"Downloading\",\"pro"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 195
recvfrom(4, "bd\r\n{\"status\":\"Downloading\",\"pro"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 195
recvfrom(4, "bd\r\n{\"status\":\"Downloading\",\"pro"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 195
recvfrom(4, "bd\r\n{\"status\":\"Downloading\",\"pro"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 195
recvfrom(4, "bd\r\n{\"status\":\"Downloading\",\"pro"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 195
recvfrom(4, "bd\r\n{\"status\":\"Downloading\",\"pro"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 19
```

Just wait until it completes.